# how to detect language from string like my php function in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to write something like below php code in python 3 to detect English, Persian and Arabic languages from title or description of **scraped** pages.

```
function language_detection($title,$description,$type){
$languageType="";
$keywordExist=0;
$string=$title." ".$description;
    $metaTitle=explode(" ",$string);
    $metaTitle=str_ireplace(" ","",$metaTitle);
    $metaSplittedKeywords="";
    $fa=0;
    $faKeywordExist=0;
    $en=0;
    $enKeywordExist=0;
    foreach($metaTitle as $splittedTitle){
        if(!preg_match("/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]/", $splittedTitle)){
            $en=1;
        }
        if(preg_match("/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]/", $splittedTitle )){
            $fa=1;
        }
    }
$enInt=0;
$faInt=0;
if($en==1 && $fa==1){$languageType="fa";$faInt=1;}
else if($en==1 && $fa==0){$languageType="en";$enInt=1;}
else if($en==0 && $fa==1){$languageType="fa";$faInt=1;}
return $languageType;
}
```

I've appreciate for any help.

Comment: Why don't you translate from PHP to Python?

Comment: Dear @DYZ, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a language detection library in python instead of using a regex match. Here's the [link](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/) to langdetect, a language detection library that currently supports 55 languages.